# How to Create Observable(s) based on Database Notification

Tags: node.js, angular

Developing a Stackoverflow-like forum, when an answer is posted for a question, only the person who asks the question is notified.

So I'm able to establish a PostgreSQL Answers table with a trigger for `notify`, and a backend node to `listen` to:

Pg

```
CREATE TABLE public.answers
(
    qid integer,  // QuestionID
    aid integer,  // AnswerID
    adetails text COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_answer_notify_api
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON public.answers
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.notify_api(\x);

CREATE FUNCTION public.notify_api()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
  PERFORM pg_notify('api', json_build_object('tablename', TG_TABLE_NAME, 'record', row_to_json(NEW))::text); 
  RETURN new;
END;
$BODY$;
```

node

```
db.connect({direct: true})          
    .then(sco =>        
        {
            sco.client.on('notification', data =>
                {
                    console.log('Received: ', data);
                })
            return sco.none('LISTEN api');  // listen to channel/event/topic named "api"
        })
    .catch(
        error=>
        {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
```

This db-to-api works out great
[image]

Now, my Angular UI should display only answers related to a specific question. Meaning Question 1 will receive subscription only related to `qid=1` not others. If I create something say an `Observable` on `data`, how to implement subscription based on `JSON.parse(data.payload).record.qid`? Given this forum's questions are dynamic, it's impossible to do things like `switch (channelName)`. Google not returning much articles/SO on this. Any advice is appreciated.

**Update**: Angular is not server-sided rendered. Communication between Angular and API backend is **http**.

Comment: Is your angular app server-side rendered, or SPA? Do you want real time updates to the web app?

Comment: How does the client receive the notifications from the server? Do you use a WebSocket? If you do, then I think the decision what to send to each client should be made on the server side, not in Angular. You can still use RxJS if you want, but do it on the server side.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu How do I tell if Angular is server-side rendered? Mine is typical .html and .ts. Need real time update.

Comment: @RonInbar Agree, naturally and logically what data to be sent should be at server side. Word `websocket` only exists in `package-lock.json`, my guess is it's not in use.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu My angular is not run by `npm run dev:ssr`, it's `ng serve`. So it's not SSR.

Comment: @RonInbar It's http, not websocket.

Comment: @Jeb50 HTTP communication is always initiated by the client, unless you use a WebSocket to keep the connection open, thereby allowing the server to send you notifications. If you don't use a WebSocket, you must periodically poll the server to see if there are any new notifications. Since you didn't include any client-side code in your question, I think you're missing part of the picture.

Comment: @RonInbar At the moment there is no mechanism to expose the notified data at API backend, so no corresponding client code yet. `Observable` should be one of the direction to go with, will study websocket as well.

Comment: @Jeb50 Observables are not an alternative to WebSockets. The only alternative to WebSockets is periodic polling. You can, however, expose the WebSocket as an Observable. See, for example, [here](https://tutorialedge.net/typescript/angular/angular-websockets-tutorial/).

Comment: Web sockets or server sent events, have a look at both and see what works best for your case

Answer (score 0):

[Angular's Web Push Notification](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-push-notifications/)